# Oracle Autopartiton by range on a Number column -issue

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning, ddl

I'm trying to auto partition using NUMTOYMINTERVAL and I keep getting error message as

```
ORA-14752: Interval expression is not a constant of the correct type
```

Below is what I'm doing .. I'm converting CYCLE_DT-which is number format (20200101) to to_date. Also, I don't wat to use virtual column to convert that number column to date, since i need to change my Dashdaord to use that column for date filter?

```
create table test
(CATEGORY VARCHAR2(40 CHAR),
AMOUNT  NUMBER,
CYCLE_DT NUMBER,-- VALUE AS 20200101
PERIOD  NUMBER --VALUE AS 202001
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (CYCLE_DT) 
INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')) 
(  
   PARTITION P2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('20190101', 'YYYYMMDD')),
   PARTITION P3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('20200101', 'YYYYMMDD'))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to calculate `PARTITION BY RANGE (CYCLE_DT)  INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))` on column which is of number datatype and not date datatype that's why you have ORA-

If you decide to store cycle_dt as date it will work.

```
CREATE TABLE mytest (
    category   VARCHAR2(40 CHAR),
    amount     NUMBER,
    cycle_dt   DATE,-- VALUE AS 20200101
    period     DATE --VALUE AS 202001
)
    PARTITION BY RANGE (
        cycle_dt
    ) INTERVAL ( numtoyminterval(1, 'MONTH') ) 
    ( PARTITION p2
        VALUES LESS THAN ( to_date(20190101, 'YYYYMMDD') ),
    PARTITION p3
        VALUES LESS THAN ( to_date(20200101, 'YYYYMMDD') )
    );
```

May I know why you are using date related columns as numbers?
Calculations date-related should be done on the proper datatype.
In your case you are first converting dates to numbers to store them in a table and then using date related calculations on these number - it's like apples and oranges; Keep in mind that date datatype allows only certain value ranges for years, months, days etc.

here's solution with number datatype:

```
CREATE TABLE mytest2 (
    category   VARCHAR2(40 CHAR),
    amount     NUMBER,
    cycle_dt   number(8,0),-- VALUE AS 20200101
    period     number(6,0) --VALUE AS 202001
)
    PARTITION BY RANGE (
        cycle_dt
    ) INTERVAL ( 10000 ) 
    ( PARTITION p2
        VALUES LESS THAN (20190101),
    PARTITION p3
        VALUES LESS THAN (20200101)
    );

insert into mytest2 values ('category', 1, '20200101', '202001');
select * from mytest2;
```

btw. what will happen in case `cycle_dt = 20209988` ? Because with number type it is possible.

Comment: Thank you. This is a legacy table where they have molded date as numeric.. sucks :-( so with number there isn't a solid way to auto partition is it? also why is  to_date(20190101, 'YYYYMMDD') ) isn't working when converting a number to date??

Comment: @stack_user no problem :) it works `select to_date(20190101, 'YYYYMMDD') from dual;`

Comment: correct so why doesn't it work when used "PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ( to_date(20190101, 'YYYYMMDD') )" ?

Comment: because you are working with number datatype ; ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

Comment: @stack_user when you use incorrect data type for interval you get: `If the data type of
           partitioning column is numeric, the interval must be a numeric
           constant.`
Error report -
ORA-14752: Interval expression is not a constant of the correct type
14752. 00000 -  "Interval expression is not a constant of the correct type"

Comment: *Cause:    You attempted to use either a nonconstant interval or an interval
           whose data type does not correspond to the partitioning column
*Action:   Use only constant expressions for the interval. If the data type of
           partitioning column is numeric, the interval must be a numeric
           constant. If the data type is of type date/time, the interval must
           be a constant of interval type

Comment: correct so how do we convert a numeric to date and use it for a range partition? I just don't want to use virtual column way.. but curios if there is any other solution that I'm missing

Comment: @stack_user btw is this interval - should it be month or maybe year ?

Answer (score 1):

There's another option, but it requires adding another column to the exsting table

example structure with a new column

```
CREATE TABLE add_column_test (
    category   VARCHAR2(40 CHAR),
    amount     NUMBER,
    cycle_dt   number(8,0),-- VALUE AS 20200101
    period     number(6,0), --VALUE AS 202001
    cycle      date not null
)
    PARTITION BY RANGE (
        cycle
    ) INTERVAL ( numtoyminterval(1, 'MONTH')) 
    ( PARTITION p2
        VALUES LESS THAN (to_date(20190101, 'YYYYMMDD')),
    PARTITION p3
        VALUES LESS THAN (to_date(20200101, 'YYYYMMDD'))
    );
    /
```

datafix for existing entries

```
UPDATE add_column_test t
set t.cycle = to_date(t.cycle_dt, 'yyyymmdd')
where t.cycle is null;
/
```

example trigger for insert into it can be also adapted for update etc.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_column_cycle BEFORE
    INSERT ON add_column_test
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.cycle IS NULL THEN
      :new.cycle := to_date(:new.cycle_dt, 'yyyymmdd');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

insert dummy data

```
insert into add_column_test(amount, cycle_dt, period, cycle) 
values (1, '20200101', '202001', null);
```

check the output

```
select * from add_column_test;
```